# Why CSS is not working in Ninja Form when I am not logged in to the site

Tags: css, styles, ninja-forms

switching from Caldera to Ninja I converted a form and inserted it on https://www.hamburg-greeter.de/en/ninjafeedback-en/.

The form looks good in preview mode and as long as I am logged in.
But when I am logged out the style is changed (no bold titles, text order in items "Website" and "Social Media".

Does anyone have an idea how this could be causes? I deactivated WP Rocket and Autoptimize caching but that did not change anything.

Thanks a lot in advance.

**Logged in:**

[image: Logged in]

**Logged out:**

[image: Logged out]

Answer (score 0):

*Found this question as I was having the same issue.*

After further digging I've found that the difference lies within the CSS - and the Plugin itself.

Ninja Forms uses its' *"Opinionated Styles"* which can be set to `Light/Dark/None`.

*you'll notice if you set it to NONE. you'll have the same look as when you're logged off.*

I looked into the code and found that when you're not logged in, for whatever reason, NINJA Forms does NOT include its Opinionated Styles in the form generation.

the primary file is `"display-opinions-light.css"` which is than broken down into a smaller `"display-opinions-light.scss"` that contains further imports of .scss files.

the location of the CSS/SCSS file(s) in question are here:

```
[your-site]/wp-content/plugins/ninja-forms/assets/css/display-opinions-light.css
```

The quickest fix to keep the look/feel you had before would be to copy the info out of `display-opinions-light.css` and dump it into a *code snippet* that will only display on your form pages, ultimately circumventing the error within Ninja Forms.

Another option would be to create a custom code snippet/CSS code and update the visuals that way to override the OP styles and have styles persist on logout.

third option (and the one I hope to go with) is to scratch Ninja Forms altogether for CF7 or Gravity which both seem better maintained and better functioning than Ninja Forms - and I have to say i dislike the way Ninja Forms tries to penny pinch and charge for every possible feature under the sun (alot of which are included out of the gate with Gravity/CF7).

Hopefully this helps - I know this question is over a year old at this point, but it has been viewed over 200 times so if not original poster, hopefully someone will find this useful.